# Magento 2.4.2: cannot override crontab.xml

Tags: magento2

With the code below, I am looking to change the cron frequency, but it doesn't take any effect.

```
   <group id="yotpo_yotpo">
        <job name="yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync" instance="Yotpo\Yotpo\Model\Jobs\OrdersSync" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>

    <job name="inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails" instance="Magento\InventoryInStorePickupSales\Model\NotifyOrdersAreReadyForPickupEmailSender" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 1 * *</schedule>
    </job>
    <job name="swissup_marketplace_job_run" instance="Swissup\Marketplace\Cron\QueueProcess" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 1 * *</schedule>
    </job>
    <job name="swissup_marketplace_job_cleanup" instance="Swissup\Marketplace\Cron\QueueCleanup" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 1 * *</schedule>
    </job>
    <job name="swissup_marketplace_cache_cleanup" instance="Swissup\Marketplace\Cron\CacheCleanup" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 1 * *</schedule>
    </job>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add each of the `<job>` node inside the `<group>` node, check their original `crontab.xml` and see which was the allocated group for running these jobs.

Also, make sure you add the `<sequence>` node in your `module.xml` file so that your module is loaded last (after the original modules) to make sure your schedule will overwrite the initial ones.

---

***LE***

Here is an example for sequence usage:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Vendor">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Swissup_Marketplace" />
            <module name="Yotpo_Yotpo" />
            <module name="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Okay, what should be the value within <sequence> node?

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Perfectmakeupmirrors_JobFrequency" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales"/>
        </sequence>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Yotpo_Yotpo"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Comment: also, there should be only one <sequence> node. check my update in the answer.

Comment: I carefully followed what you wrote. Only name="inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails" got the new schedule.

Comment: maybe you need to check whether the group you are defining the crons under is the correct one. oh and not to mention that it's not a good idea to have a module that handles multiple crons from multiple modules.

Comment: All seems correct. Is it possible for me to share both crontab.xml and module.xml with you to check and suggest any correction?